# installing php app via composer

Tags: php

I wanted to install via composer given information like this

```
{
   "name": "bitcoin app",
   "require": {
       "slim/slim": "2.2.0"
   }
}
```

I am unable to recognize do I have to write this to a php file and upload to the server?

Comment: In `composer.json` file then `composer install` and anytime you need a package you can require it using this syntax `composer require your_package_name` if that package for production if it was for development purpose you can say `composer require --dev your_package_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) is a PHP based dependency management system.

That's a snippet of a `composer.json` file used to get & manage initial dependencies, to use it you'll need to have PHP & [Composer installed](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements) and then create a file called `composer.json` in the location you'd like to have the project created.

Once you'd done that run `composer install` to get the dependencies. This won't actually install an app persay, you'll still need to make that yourself.

Scotch.io has a [decent beginners guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-composer) to Composer if you're uncertain about how to install it & what it's actually used for.

Comment: composer install this i the main thing I am unable to get nor able to fiund in the tutorials do I have to write this in cmd ?

Comment: Yes, once you've installed composer you can run it via command line. If it's a shared host you'll probably run it via `php composer.phar install`. Definitely check out that guide I posted, it'll save you time in the long run

Answer (score 0):

No. You should write this to a json file named `composer.json`.

Then use composer to install the package: `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

1) First you need to create or found composer.json

2) Then write your code in this file

3) In last you have to update composer.