# Braintree PHP required version conflict

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree

I am trying to set up the serverside Braintree PHP library on my server.
I downloaded the Braintree PHP library from the link they provided and unzipped it and uploaded to my server. I created a config.php file which contains the path for the PHP library on my server and defines my API credentials as follows:

```
<?php require_once 'btphp/lib/Braintree.php'; Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('yqjkd7r5kdtdyq9d');Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('ssjcrbg3qff8cnk2');Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('6fd935bc49457f318027b52bd262572e');$clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate(["customerId" => $aCustomerId]);?>
```

On execution of the file, a Fatal error is given saying that PHP version 7.2 is required.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Braintree\Exception' with message 'PHP version >= 7.2.0 required' in /home/content/37/11957537/html/ua/btphp/lib/Braintree.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/37/11957537/html/ua/btconfig.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/content/37/11957537/html/ua/btphp/lib/Braintree.php on line 10
```

Braintree docs clearly state the following:

> AVAILABILITY
>   The Braintree PHP SDK requires PHP version 5.4.0 or higher and the PHP cURL extension.

my web hosting PHP version is 5.6

Anybody can explain why is this happening.

Comment: Dont use v4.0.0, https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blame/master/composer.json#L13 your welcome.

Comment: Can you clarify more please

Comment: 20 days ago they made an update which requires >= 7.2.0, either use the version before that change or update PHP, switch hosts etc..

Comment: How to get the version before that change please

Comment: As Lawrence said. Since your server is using php 5.6  it wont work. You need to use an older version of braintree. use this version https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/releases/tag/3.40.0

Comment: `composer require braintree/braintree_php:3.40.0 `

Comment: I don't understand the role of the composer here and how to use it

Comment: Then the releases link above given by @Hans-EricLippke will be what you're after, though its another can of worms integrating it if the lib is composer based.

Comment: How to use composer then

Comment: All info for composer can be seen here. https://getcomposer.org/  This answer has an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897113/installing-php-app-via-composer/42897168

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue. You need to comment these as show in image (9 ,10,11) lines in Braintree.php .
[image]

This work for me.